# Student is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have
**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Student.Models;
using System.IO;

namespace Ucebnice.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public ViewResult Details()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Student Details Page";
            ViewBag.Header = "Student Details";
            Student student = new Student()
            {
                StudentId = 101,
                Name = "James",
                Branch = "CSE",
                Section = "A",
                Gender = "Male"
            };

            ViewBag.Student = student;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Student.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And it writes me this error **"Student is a namespace but is used like a type"**. It has got problem with **Student student = new Student()**.
I followed this tutorial https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/viewbag-asp-net-core-mvc/ but I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Please show your student class including the namespace that it's in.

Comment: Sure, I updated code snippet.

Comment: Your controller doesn't have `using Student.Models` in it, so the only `Student` it can see is the root of that namespace, not the class within.

Comment: It is there - fifth using, if we mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename your `Student` class or the `Student.Models` namespace. Alternatively, you could qualify the reference like this:

```
var student = new Student.Models.Student()
{
    StudentId = 101,
    Name = "James",
    Branch = "CSE",
    Section = "A",
    Gender = "Male"
};
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution is working perfectly . I would like to ask how should I rename it if I want to use it just  "Student student = new Student()".

Comment: The `Student.Models` namespace is equivalent to a `Models` namespace nested within a `Student` namespace. You could rename this to anything at all such as `StudentABCD.Models` or `SomeOtherWord.Models`. You could also just remove the `.` and have a namespace called `StudentModels`.